# Fluent UI Detail List - I want to include the contextual menu in column headers for sorting and filtering

Tags: reactjs, office-fabric

I am using Fluent UI DetailsList. I want  a functionality to sort and filtering to choose when column header is clicked in the detailList.

Filtering would be like, when Clicking on filter by it should ask for filtering as per below image

[image]

Sorting should give 2 option to choose (Ascending/Descending)

Comment: @Manoj, I have a somewhat similar scenario, mine is just a plain textbox for filtering. Have you manage to resolve this?